# Passing values dynamically to child component react native

Tags: react-native

**App.js**

```
  render() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
    <Button
      title="Learn More"
      color="#841584"
      accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
      onPress={() => {
        (this.state.dadda = '2017-09-07');
       }}
    />
    <EventCalendar
      eventTapped={this._eventTapped.bind(this)}
      events={this.state.events}
      width={width}
      initDate={this.state.dadda}
      scrollToFirst={false}
     />
  </View>
); }
```

This is my parent component ,I want to pass initDate to event calendar component,I want to update the date when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You should not **mutate** the `state` by *assigning value to the `state` variable directly* but instead use `setState` to acheive that.

```
<Button
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
  onPress={() => this.setState({dadda: '2017-09-07'})}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting `dadaa` into the state is not correct, use `this.setState` function instead, have a look at the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Change your onPress handler to

```
...
< Button
  title = "Learn More"
  color = "#841584"
  accessibilityLabel = "Learn more about this purple button"
  onPress = {
    () => {
      this.setState({
        dadda:'2017-09-07'
      });
    }
  }
/>
...
```

Also, don't declare the function inside render, rather keep it at the class level like

```
onPressHandler = () => {
  this.setState({
    dadaa: 'aaaa'
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <
    Button
      ...
      onPress = {this.onPressHandler}
      ...
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Hope this will help!